# Gradle doesn't add jni libs to aar

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a library project which has SDK.jar which has libs folder with *.so libs.

[image]

I added this jar to my library project like below

[image]

The problem is that the output .aar file has only Java classes from SDK.jar but doesn't have libs folder with *.so libs.

If I add my library project to sample project it works fine and final apk has .so libs but when I add as the .aar library it doesn't have .so libs and works incorrectly.

Also, it has started to happen since I updated my gradle plugin to 3.0.0.

My full `build.gradle` of my library project.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 42
        versionName "beta 1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {

        mock {
            initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/SDK.jar')

    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'

    implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.9.4@aar'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'

    implementation 'com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:1.5.3'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    mockImplementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    implementation 'com.pushtorefresh.storio:sqlite:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.pushtorefresh.storio:sqlite-annotations:1.13.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.pushtorefresh.storio:sqlite-annotations-processor:1.13.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.ext.supportVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:${rootProject.ext.supportVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:${rootProject.ext.supportVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${rootProject.ext.playServices}"

    implementation 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.joshdholtz.sentry:sentry-android:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'

    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: please post your library build.gradle

Comment: @Akhil I've added

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `implementation files('libs/SDK.jar')` with  `compileOnly files('libs/SDK.jar')` in my library project and added `implementation files('libs/SDK.jar')` to my sample project.